# Mockito - any of java.sql.Clob

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I am trying to mock a method which is used during execution of a parent method by:

```
Mockito.when(sisSQL.getDocumentAsString(Mockito.any(java.sql.Clob.class))).thenReturn(expected);
```

The method that I am trying do mock:

```
protected String getDocumentAsString(Clob clob) throws IOException, SQLException {
    if (clob == null) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return new String(getDocument(clob), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```

I am mocking every other methods in the same way but here in result I am getting:

```
But got org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced argument matcher detected here:

-> at pl.sygnity.common.db.SisSQLTest$callDBFuncTest.callDBFuncReturnsValue(SisSQLTest.java:91)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

    at pl.xxx.common.db.SisSQLTest$callDBFuncTest.callDBFuncReturnsValue(SisSQLTest.java:91)
```

Why is that?
Thanks

Comment: Your code is fine. Problem can be caused by code before it.

Comment: I note that you're trying to mock a method _on a class_. Your life will be much better if you can refactor this to an interface.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-  You are right, however I cannot do this.